# Git not recognised on Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, git, anaconda, theano

I have installed Git on my system and the `git` command is working fine in the command prompt. I also updated my path varaibles to reflect the address of git bin and cmd. Now, I want to use the following command to install Theano library using Anaconda Prompt -
`pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git`

The error I am getting is -
Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git C:\Users\Kritika\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vp5qj204-build
Cannot find command 'git'

I googled and found a lot of things but nothing seems to work for me. Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Comment: I would very much like to understand why does it help?!

Comment: @phd  I don't understand your question.  If I'm understanding correctly, it's kind of like you're asking "why does typing "ls" into bash give you information about your file directories?"   Answer: it does.  Who cares?  You have a job to do.  Type it and move on with your life and go have some fun later, maybe take a walk in the park or grab a beer

Remember the tool for later as well; it will help you install future tools that will help your technical "carpentry"  :)

Comment: @Nathan No, my question is: In what way the command is better than the command in the question? The only difference is `git://` protocol vs `https://` but the error is "Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone". How does `https://` help? Actually I don't believe it helps at all.

Comment: Oh.  As written above, I did not understand.  Anyway, for some reason, OP accepted this answer.  So perhaps for them it helped, but we'd have to ask them.  You're probably right and there's no difference :)

Answer (score 3):

First run the command

`conda install -c anaconda git`

then run

`git clone https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git`